# What does `*` mean in a C `typedef struct` declaration?

Tags: c, struct

I'm looking at a `C` struct with some syntax I've never seen before. The structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct structExample {
   int member1;
   int member2
} * structNAME;
```

I know that normally with a structure of:

```
typedef struct structExample {
   int member1;
   int member2
} structNAME;
```

I could refer to a member of the second struct definition by saying:

```
structNAME* tempStruct = malloc(sizeof(structNAME));
// (intitialize members)
tempstruct->member1;
```

What does that extra `*` in the the first struct definition do, and how would I reference members of the first struct definition?

Comment: I would never do this, unless there's a gun between my eyes

Comment: Possible duplicate of your C book

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means the defined type is a pointer type. This is an equivalent way to declare the type:

```
struct structExample {
    int member1;
    int member2;
};
typedef struct structExample * structNAME;
```

You would use it like this:

```
structNAME mystruct = malloc (sizeof (struct structExample));
mystruct->member1 = 42;
```

Comment: Liberally omitting some kind of malloc, isn't it?

Comment: you will definitely not use it like this.

Comment: I got it, the spirit of the answer was there. Thanks to UmNyobe and all others that replied.

Comment: @Osley: Microsoft uses this syntax a lot in the WinAPI. E.g. `typedef struct tagMYSTRUCT { /* ... */ } MYSTRRUCT, *PMYSTRUCT;`. Using this, you have a typedef `MYSTRUCT` for `struct tagMYSTRUCT` and even a pointer type `PMYSTRUCT` for `struct tagMYSTRUCT *`.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that, except from in Microsoft's odd, ancient coding standard, typedef:ing away pointers is generally considered as very bad coding practice in C programming.

Comment: Hiding pointer types behind a typedef is often a recipe for heartburn.  Unless the type is meant to be truly opaque and not manually dereferenced by the programmer (i.e., just passed back and forth to the API), it's better to explicitly declare a pointer as a pointer, i.e., `typedef struct ex {...} mystruct; mystruct *ptr;`.

Comment: Oops was to quick there, thanks to @iain for fixing it :) And I agree this is bad practice. Personally i prefer to not typedef structs at all.

Answer (score 2):

The typedef makes these two statements the same

```
struct structExample *myStruct;
structName myStruct;
```

It makes `structName` stand for a pointer to `struct structExample`

As an opinion, I dislike this coding style, because it makes it harder to know whether a variable is a pointer or not. It helps if you have

```
typedef struct structExample * structExampleRef;
```

to give a hint that it is a pointer to `struct structExample`;

Answer (score 1):

`structNAME` is defined as a pointer on `struct structExample`. SO you can do

```
structNAME tempStructPtr = malloc(sizeOf(struct structExample));
tempStructPtr->member1 = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The secret to understanding these is that you can put `typedef` in front of any declaration, to turn `TYPENAME VARIABLENAME` into `typedef TYPENAME ALIASEDNAME`.

Since the asterisk can't be part of the `VARIABLENAME` part if this was a plain declaration, it has to be part of the type. An asterisk following a type name means "pointer to" the preceding type.

Compare this:

```
typedef int * my_int_pointer;
```

It's exactly the same, except in your case instead of `int` you're declaring a `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

In that case (* structNAME) is pointer variable of that structure..